# SSL/TLS 1.2 on Apache with openssl 1.0.1

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl

I built and installed openssl 1.0.1.  How do I force Apache to use TLS 1.2 Ciphers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS 1.2 is covered in these 2 documents;
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6176

Basically the latter doc is Prohibiting SSL 2.0 from being negotiated by TLS1.2 and this is the default for httpd 2.2 shipped with fedora; eg `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2`

However your question was about CipherSuites which are also covered in those docs; By the looks of it, the only [mandatory cipher suite](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-65) for TLS 1.2 is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

```
Appendix C. Cipher Suite Definitions
Cipher Suite                            Key        Cipher         Mac
                                        Exchange
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA            RSA          AES_128_CBC  SHA
```

This says that the server must provide an RSA certificate for key exchange, and that the cipher should be AES_128_CBC and the Mac SHA.

From the httpd mod_ssl docs, this translates to;

```
 SSLCipherSuite aRSA:kRSA:AES128-CBC:SHA
```

which is  documented here;
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite

Comment: After upgrading openssl from 1.0.0e to 1.0.1 and changing the SSLCipherSuite, do I need to rebuild or make any configuration tweaks to apache2?

Comment: At a guess, I think that if you restart apache2 that if it starts then it would have upgraded OK. However I would confirm the log messages for the restart are OK.